# Fragment using DataBinding in kotlin (android)?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, data-binding, fragment

I am following **android** tutorial using **kotlin** provided by **google**
in the lesson of `Fragment` I noticed that they used two ways to link the `class` with layout :

between `fragment_about.xml` and `AboutFragment` they used

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_about, container, false)
```

and
between `fragment_title.xml` and `TitleFragment.kt` they used

```
    val binding: FragmentTitleBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
                inflater, R.layout.fragment_title, container, false)
return binding.root
```

what the difference between the two ways and when we use each of them ?
android trivia App
[github](https://github.com/udacity/andfun-kotlin-android-trivia)

Thanks

Comment: I would recommend taking a look at the documentation on [data binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding). Should give you a better overview than a short answer here.

Comment: hi @HenryTwist thanks for your answer 
As I said I'm following the course from the beginning so I followed a colab about dataBinding and I know how to use it and when to use it, but they didn't talk about the difference between Linking layout with view using databinding or Inflater in documentation this is why I asked my question

Comment: Well if you just inflate your layout, you won't get any of the benefits with data binding. To facilitate data binding you have to link the layout with the binding classes. If you intend on using data binding you would generally never want to inflate the layout with the inflater.

Comment: @HenryTwist ah so the inflater just link the view with layout but we won't have the benefits of databinding like replacing findViewById etc ... and here they used inflater because the don't need it (benefits of dataBinding) and the view is empty this is why they used inflater instead of dataBinding right ?

Comment: Yes pretty much. Think about the inflater just reading the XML file and creating a proper view structure. Then the data binding inflater does the same thing, but then has the extra job of linking the ID's to references etc.

Comment: Okay it's very helpful, Thank you so much